# Why is the 'this' variable not the expected value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having an issue with the following code.  On the lines with the "console.log", the 'this' variable should contain 'Object Chart', but, instead, contains 'path.line'.  Hence, the reference to xscale is undefined.  Why am I getting this?  This error occurs under Chrome and Firefox.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3.0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="d3.v2.js"></script>
<script>
var kev_vs_rho= [{ 
values: [{x: 0.01, y: 0.2058},{x: 0.03, y: 0.2039},{x: 0.05, y: 0.2020}] }, {
values: [{x: 0.01, y: 1.6468},{x: 0.03, y: 1.6303},{x: 0.05, y: 1.6137}] }, ];
kev_vs_rho.minX=0.01;
kev_vs_rho.maxX=0.99;
kev_vs_rho.minY=0.01;
kev_vs_rho.maxY=33.66;
</script>

<div id="chart1"> </div>
<script>

"use strict";

var Chart = function ( _width, _height, _data, _div ) {
    this.data = _data;
    this.div = _div;

    this.idx1 = 0;
    this.select1 = 0;

    this.margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 80};
    this.width = _width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = _height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    this.xscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([this.data.minX, this.data.maxX])
        .range([0, this.width]);

    this.yscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([this.data.minY, this.data.maxY])
        .range([this.height, 0]);

    this.lineA = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
             console.log( this ); // <<== is 'path.line', not object Chart
             console.log( this.xscale ); // <<== undefined

             return this.xscale(d.x); // <<== undefined
             })
        .y(function (d) { return this.yscale(d.y); });

    this.svg1 = d3.select(_div).append("div").append("svg")
        .datum(_data[this.select1].values)
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");

    this.lineB = this.svg1.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .datum(this.data[this.select1].values)
        .attr("d", this.lineA);
};

var chart1 = new Chart( 960, 400, kev_vs_rho, "#chart1");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is not a "variable", but a special keyword bound to the current execution

Comment: A common method for this is to declare a variable at the top of the function like `var self = this;`, then use `self` everywhere that you are referring to the parent `function`...everywhere else where you want to refer to the specific value of `this` in nested functions, you can use `this` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use `this` directly in the Chart constructor(not in an anonymous function passed as a parameter) or in a method of a Chart object or manually use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with an Chat object, `this` wouldn't reference a Chart object.

What you can do is explicitly set a variable to the chart object and use that in the functions.

```
<script>

"use strict";

var Chart = function ( _width, _height, _data, _div ) {
    self = this;
    this.data = _data;
    this.div = _div;

    this.idx1 = 0;
    this.select1 = 0;

    this.margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 80};
    this.width = _width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = _height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    this.xscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([this.data.minX, this.data.maxX])
        .range([0, this.width]);

    this.yscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([this.data.minY, this.data.maxY])
        .range([this.height, 0]);

    this.lineA = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
             console.log( self ); // <<== is 'path.line', not object Chart
             console.log( self.xscale ); // <<== undefined

             return self.xscale(d.x); // <<== undefined
             })
        .y(function (d) { return self.yscale(d.y); });

    this.svg1 = d3.select(_div).append("div").append("svg")
        .datum(_data[this.select1].values)
        .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
        .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");

    this.lineB = this.svg1.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .datum(this.data[this.select1].values)
        .attr("d", this.lineA);
};

var chart1 = new Chart( 960, 400, kev_vs_rho, "#chart1");

</script>
```