# Javascript, nested eventhandler and this

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I have this javascript class:

```
var Server = (function () {

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function Server(serverDefinition) {
    this.definition = serverDefinition;
    this.status = false;
}

Server.prototype.start = function () {
    this.process = spawn('java', ['-jar', this.definition.jarfile]);
    this.status = true;

    this.process.on('exit', function(code, signal){
        this.status = false;
        console.log('Server stopped: code=' + code + ', signal=' + signal);
    });

    this.process.stdout.on('data', function(data){ console.log('stdout: ' + data);});
    this.process.stderr.on('data', function(data){ console.log('stderr: ' + data);});
};

return Server;
```

})();

My problem is that `this` inside of `this.process.on('exit', ... )` referes to `process`, not `Server` as I would like it to.

What is the best pattern of dealing with this case? A `_self = this` ? In that case, where should that line be inserted, and should I stop referring to `this` and only use `_self` instead?

Comment: similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167630/why-is-the-this-variable-not-the-expected-value

Answer (score 2):

You could create a local variable that holds a reference to the `this` in the functions scope, this will work because in JavaScript, the scope of a variable is defined by its location within the source code, and nested functions have access to variables declared in their outer scope.[[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)]

```
Server.prototype.start = function () {
    var serv = this; // Reference to local object for use in inner-functions

    this.process = spawn('java', ['-jar', this.definition.jarfile]);
    this.status = true;

    this.process.on('exit', function(code, signal){
        serv.status = false;
        console.log('Server stopped: code=' + code + ', signal=' + signal);
    });

    this.process.stdout.on('data', function(data){ console.log('stdout: ' + data);});
    this.process.stderr.on('data', function(data){ console.log('stderr: ' + data);});
};
```

In my opinion it is best practice to keep refering to `this` where ever possible to make clear what you are refering to, one might miss a re-assignment of the used local variable while debugging making it hard to find errors.

Comment: +1. If you use this pattern consistently, others will soon learn to look for the lcoal assignment. I also like the use of the constructor name for the instance (Server -> server) so it's obvious that it's the instance (once you know the pattern) so `server.process = …` and `server.status = …` reinforce the scheme.

Comment: Bonus question: I have changed my code as you suggest, and it no longer makes a new status property on the process object. But it doesn't change the right status property either. I get the log-statement, but `this.status`, or `serv.status`, remains `true`. Is there anything else that is wrong?  I also tried to clear the process property in the exit event, but that lead to big trouble...

Comment: Bonus answer: I put the `serv` variable outside of the start function. I must say I have trouble understanding this... (pun not intended...)

Comment: Where did you put it then? If it is global you will overwrite the current value whenever you start a new server.